# Access & VBA, what is best "architecture" for a large, scalable application

Tags: sql, ms-access, architecture, vba

I would like to know what is the best approach concerning mixing Access, SQL & VBA.
Because I am currently working on a massive application, which is likely to evolve in future and I am asking myself if I did right.

I choosed to "hard code" most of my SQL queries in independant VBA modules, only giving values of criteria (for `SELECT/DELETE`) or fields (for `INSERT/UPDATE`) as parameters.
I firstly found this convenient since all I had to do was to make procedure call in my forms code, just passing the wanted values of my controls.

But the problem is that if I add a new field, rename my table or rename a field, I will have to rewrite all queries concerning that table one by one... That's quite annoying

I would like to know if there is existing a "standard architecture" to conveniently work on a scalable application in Access ?

By scalable I mean the database itself AND the application logic.

Comment: If you want a large, scalable application, my suggestion is not to use Access and VBA at all. Instead: use C# and SQL-Server.

Comment: Thx for your fast answer, I knew that Access was not the best tool to provide that kind of application but I did not have the choice, I am on a traineeship and working with MS Access is imposed. I do not need an extremly robust architecture, just a way to make the code a bit more maintainable and not completely sensitive to small changes ;-(

Comment: I agreestraight to SQL Server and a language not contained within, like .net vb/C#.Your question seems to contradict itself though, you say you are passing the arguments, for actions, but if you are passing parameters in, then surely these are fields that require it and new fields would require inspection/code change.  If you use an ADO connection, you can open the DB schema to get details of tables and fields etc, so you could do this with prefixed fields, so say UP_Firstname,would then allow you to open the schema and get field names beginning UP_ meaning updatable..

Comment: It's tricky in Access,replication was good, but a bit clunky

Comment: "then surely these are fields that require it and new fields would require inspection/code change", yes that's exactly the problem I have ! I will see if the trick you gave me can make things easier for me

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that without adding extra code, you couldn't control any updates deletes properly, the sql will be select x,y,z where z=100, if you add fields a,b,c and these require select a,b,c,x,y,z where a=100 and z=200, then you have to revisit the code in order to do this, fields not requiring this, you could use select * where z=100 and a,b and c would be included.

Comment: You are right, until you do not use new field as criteria, DELETE, UPDATE and SELECT are not that much big deals. But w/ INSERT you must take in consideration any new field. Mmh, in my case it mights be manageable since 'SELECT *' does not annoy me that much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... the problem is that if I add a new field, rename my table or
>   rename a field, I will have to rewrite all queries concerning that
>   table one by one

I suggest you use `QueryDef` objects (saved queries) instead of keeping the SQL statement text in code modules.

Then, when you have queries which reference a table or field name which later gets changed, you need not necessarily manually identify which queries need revision and edit those one at a time.  You could use something like [swapTblNamesInQueryDefs()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1223231/77335).  I wrote that for table names, but it should work for field names, too.

If you continue to keep your SQL statements in code modules, you could do something similar with find & replace.  However a potential complication there is that the word replacement would not be confined to only SQL statement text.  That would be a problem when the target word is present elsewhere in your VBA code but you don't want those occurrences replaced.  That is not a problem when your SQL is in `QueryDef` objects.

Adding new fields is more challenging.  You could use `swapTblNamesInQueryDefs()` in *DisplayOnly* mode to examine the SQL from queries which contain the name of the modified table.  However, I don't see any automatable way to identify which of those queries should be modified and make the needed changes.